# Angular Application Automatically Calling All APIs without being opened in browser

Tags: angular, api, express, bad-gateway

When angular application  is being served using `sudo npm run serve_dev:ssr` then it should wait for url `localhost:4400` being opened in browser and after that call all mentioned APIs to display in UI. But issue is that when application is served then it automatically calls all APIs without opening localhost url in browser.

I want to know why this is happening??Is there something that I have missed?
Also this problem is causing 502 bad gateway error when application is deployed on server.

Answer (score 1):

There are things you need to look into while doing SSR. Before running anything, you may need to check which platform you are making calls from. For example, the code below:

```js
import { Component, PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-postfeed',
  templateUrl: './postfeed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./postfeed.component.css']
})
export class PostfeedComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platform: Object) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
        // here you can run any browser specific code, like:
        window.alert('This will run only in the browser!');
      }
  }
}
```

This code is an example to check whether the platform is a browser or not. If you user isPlatformBrowser for your call, you can defer API calls for browser.

Thanks!